# Java fx comobox or listview help. Populate a list in real time.

Tags: javafx

I am trying to create a combo box or something similar to that which populates a list upon the user entry. For example, when entering the state, if they enter N, I want the user to see a list of states starting with N without them clicking a button. I am using Java FX.

Comment: Have you read the documentation on say, Combo Box?

Comment: Yes, I did but can't seem to find anything like that. All I see is how to change colors or customize, but there is no real time manipulation examples I can see.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this class

```
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.control.ComboBox;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyCode;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyEvent;

class AutoCompleteComboBoxListener<T> implements EventHandler<KeyEvent> {
    private ComboBox comboBox;
    private StringBuilder sb;
    private ObservableList<T> data;
    private boolean moveCaretToPos = false;
    private int caretPos;

    public AutoCompleteComboBoxListener(final ComboBox comboBox) {
        this.comboBox = comboBox;
        this.sb = new StringBuilder();
        this.data = comboBox.getItems();
        this.comboBox.setEditable(true);
        this.comboBox.setOnKeyPressed(t -> comboBox.hide());
        this.comboBox.setOnKeyReleased(this);
    }

    public void handle(KeyEvent event) {
        if(event.getCode() == KeyCode.UP) {
            this.caretPos = -1;
            this.moveCaret(this.comboBox.getEditor().getText().length());
        } else if(event.getCode() == KeyCode.DOWN) {
            if(!this.comboBox.isShowing()) {
                this.comboBox.show();
            }

            this.caretPos = -1;
            this.moveCaret(this.comboBox.getEditor().getText().length());
        } else {
            if(event.getCode() == KeyCode.BACK_SPACE) {
                this.moveCaretToPos = true;
                this.caretPos = this.comboBox.getEditor().getCaretPosition();
            } else if(event.getCode() == KeyCode.DELETE) {
                this.moveCaretToPos = true;
                this.caretPos = this.comboBox.getEditor().getCaretPosition();
            }

            if(event.getCode() != KeyCode.RIGHT && event.getCode() != KeyCode.LEFT && !event.isControlDown() && event.getCode() != KeyCode.HOME && event.getCode() != KeyCode.END && event.getCode() != KeyCode.TAB) {
                ObservableList list = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

                for(int t = 0; t < this.data.size(); ++t) {
                    if(this.data.get(t) != null && this.data.get(t).toString().toLowerCase().startsWith(this.comboBox.getEditor().getText().toLowerCase())) {
                        list.add(this.data.get(t));
                    }
                }

                String var4 = this.comboBox.getEditor().getText();
                this.comboBox.setItems(list);
                this.comboBox.getEditor().setText(var4);
                if(!this.moveCaretToPos) {
                    this.caretPos = -1;
                }

                this.moveCaret(var4.length());
                if(!list.isEmpty()) {
                    this.comboBox.show();
                }

            }
        }
    }

    private void moveCaret(int textLength) {
        if(this.caretPos == -1) {
            this.comboBox.getEditor().positionCaret(textLength);
        } else {
            this.comboBox.getEditor().positionCaret(this.caretPos);
        }

        this.moveCaretToPos = false;
    }
}
```

The you would call it like so

```
new AutoCompleteComboBoxListener<>(comboBoxName);
```